# combine literal string with regex using grep

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to put together a GREP search for the following:

```
'<iframe' + *any characters* + '<body'
```

So basically, searching a DEV codebase for files that have open  tag followed by any characters followed by an open  tag. Is there a way to mix literal strings and "wildcard" type expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-greedy `.*` with grep.

```
grep -Prinl '<iframe.*?<body' /path/to/codebase
```